# Access VNC on Ubuntu through web browser?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop, vnc

I want to install desktop GUI on my Ubuntu server (for development usage) and then be able to see my remote screen through the web browser with VNC.

Is this possible? If so, could you provide me some guides/tutorials for installing the VNC (there are different versions) on the Ubuntu?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is an article [**here**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=541656&highlight=ssh+vncviewer) on how to do this with firefox ( and possibly other java enabled browsers ).

Comment: I would really like to use javascript instead of java on the web browser.

Comment: VNC uses a Java applet to act as a client in the browser.  It you really want to do it in javascript you will have to rewrite the applet into javascript unless someone has done so already.  Don't expect a lot of support for your client.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at TightVNC out of the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 1):

vncserver and tightvnc both have Java applets which can be added to your configuration. These are usually servered from a in the 5800 range instead of the 5900 range.  For VNV port 1 you would browse to http://server.example.com:5801.  This will trigger the applet to download and connect.

You will need to setup regular VNC access first.  The README file included with the tightvnc-java package includes setup directions.  The applet can be served up from an existing web server such as apache.  The java code can be run standalone which you may want to use to test your configuration if you are embedding it in a web page.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't exactly what you want, but [NoMachineNX](http://www.nomachine.com/products.php) has a [Web Companion](http://www.nomachine.com/screenshot/companion.php) for accessing remote machines in a Web Browser via a Java applet.  There are DEB packages available for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at guacamole. I used it for some similar requirements and performed pretty well. Just know that it is a tomcat web-app. If you have questions, let me know.